# How do I switch Yarn versions/check where my Yarn is installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, yarnpkg

Hello I tried the following:

`yarn -v` 
=> 
`1.3.2`

`brew list yarn`
=>

```
/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/bin/yarn
/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/bin/yarnpkg
/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/libexec/bin/ (5 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/libexec/lib/ (2 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/libexec/package.json
```

`brew switch yarn 1.13.0`
=>

```
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/0.24.6
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.7.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.12.3
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0
```

But `yarn -v` still =>  `1.3.2`

It's not on npm either
`npm list -g --depth=0`
=>

```
/Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/@particles/dashboard
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/@particles/navigation-tiers
├── create-react-native-app@1.0.0
├── exp@51.4.0
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/my-procore
├── node-gyp@3.8.0
├── npm@5.6.0
└── react-native-cli@2.0.1
```

Comment: Did you install hadoop? It also install a yarn binary. Check `brew info yarn`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the **actual** instead of the `yarn` command that you are executing on your shell using the `which` command

```
$ which yarn
/usr/local/bin/yarn
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/yarn
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hanxue  admin  30 Jan 17 01:59 /usr/local/bin/yarn -> ../Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/bin/yarn
```

There is a possibility that you are executing a different version of `yarn` installed by nvm. I would not recommend using a mix of `nvm` and `brew`. Both are excellent options for installing and switching between multiple versions of node, but using both might cause conflict and confusion.